# Handling hexadecimal strings and byte arrays

Tags: c#

I recently ran into a problem that requires me to work with hexadecimal strings and wanted to learn how the encoding/decoding process works. Using a bunch of help from posts on SO I was able to cobble together a `Hexadecimal` struct with the static methods `GetBytes` and `GetString`.

**Usage:**

```
var x = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello world!");
var y = Hexadecimal.GetString(x, "0x"); // value: "0x48656C6C6F20776F726C6421"
var z = Hexadecimal.GetBytes(y, 2); // value: new byte[] { 0x48, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x6F, 0x20, 0x77, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x6C, 0x64, 0x21 }
```

**Notes:**

- The most important thing is that the methods properly handle all possible inputs.
- I wanted to avoid lookup tables of hard-coded "magic" values and calculate them instead.
- Performance must suffer as little as possible while trying accomplish any other goals.
- Normally unacceptable variables names such as `m`, `s`, and `t` are used because I personally believe that it makes this particular code easier to reason about.

**Code:**

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a single byte in hexadecimal notation.
/// </summary>
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 2, Size = 4)]
public struct Hexadecimal
{
    private const string ALPHABET = "0123456789ABCDEFabcdef";

    private static readonly uint[] m_byteToHexMap = Enumerable
        .Range(0, 256)
        .Select(i => (((uint)(GetChar((byte)(i & 0b1111)) << 16)) | GetChar((byte)(i >> 4))))
        .ToArray();
    private static readonly unsafe Hexadecimal* m_byteToHexMapPointer = ((Hexadecimal*)GCHandle.Alloc(m_byteToHexMap, GCHandleType.Pinned).AddrOfPinnedObject());
    private static readonly byte[] m_hexToByteMap = Enumerable
        .Range(0, 103)
        .Select(i => (ALPHABET.Contains((char)i) ? GetNybble((char)i) : ((byte)255)))
        .ToArray();
    private static readonly unsafe byte* m_hexToByteMapPointer = ((byte*)GCHandle.Alloc(m_hexToByteMap, GCHandleType.Pinned).AddrOfPinnedObject());

    [FieldOffset((sizeof(char) * 0))]
    private readonly char m_high;
    [FieldOffset((sizeof(char) * 1))]
    private readonly char m_low;

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the left symbol of this <see cref="Hexadecimal"/> value.
    /// </summary>
    public char High { get => m_high; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the right symbol of this <see cref="Hexadecimal"/> value.
    /// </summary>
    public char Low { get => m_low; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a hexadecimal string into an array of bytes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The hexadecimal string that will be converted.</param>
    /// <param name="prefixLength">The length of the prefix to be skipped over.</param>
    public static unsafe byte[] GetBytes(string value, int prefixLength) {
        if (prefixLength < 0) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(message: "prefix length cannot be less than zero", paramName: nameof(prefixLength));
        }

        if (value.IsNull()) {
            return null;
        }

        var stringLength = checked(value.Length - prefixLength);

        if (stringLength < 1) {
#if (NET40 || NET45 || NET451 || NET452)
            return new byte[0];
#else
            return Array.Empty<byte>();
#endif
        }

        if (stringLength.IsOdd()) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(message: "hexadecimal string cannot have an odd length", paramName: nameof(value));
        }

        var count = (stringLength >> 1);
        var result = new byte[count];

        fixed (char* source = value)
        fixed (byte* target = &result[0]) {
            var m = m_hexToByteMapPointer;
            var s = ((Hexadecimal*)(source + prefixLength));
            var t = target;

            while (0 < count--) {
                var high = (*s).High;
                var low = (*s).Low;

                if (((high < 103) && (low < 103)) && ((m[high] < 255) && (m[low] < 255))) {
                    *t = ((byte)(((uint)(m[high] << 4)) | m[low]));
                }
                else {
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(message: ("invalid hexadecimal string encountered: " + high + low));
                }

                s++;
                t++;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a hexadecimal string into an array of bytes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The hexadecimal string that will be converted.</param>
#if !(NET40)
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
#endif
    public static byte[] GetBytes(string value) {
        return GetBytes(value, 0);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts an array of bytes into a hexadecimal string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The array of bytes that will be converted.</param>
    /// <param name="prefix">The prefix that will be appended to the hexadecimal string.</param>
    public static unsafe string GetString(byte[] value, string prefix) {
        if (value.IsNull()) {
            return null;
        }

        prefix = (prefix ?? string.Empty);

        if (value.IsEmpty()) {
            return prefix;
        }

        var count = value.Length;
        var result = new string('☠', ((count << 1) + prefix.Length));

        fixed (byte* source = &value[0])
        fixed (char* target = result) {
            for (var i = 0; i < prefix.Length; i++) {
                *(target + i) = prefix[i];
            }

            var m = m_byteToHexMapPointer;
            var s = source;
            var t = ((Hexadecimal*)(target + prefix.Length));

            while (0 < count--) {
                *t = m[*s];

                s++;
                t++;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts an array of bytes into a hexadecimal string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The array of bytes that will be converted.</param>
#if !(NET40)
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
#endif
    public static unsafe string GetString(byte[] value) {
        return GetString(value, string.Empty);
    }

#if !(NET40)
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
#endif
    private static char GetChar(byte value) { // https://stackoverflow.com/a/14333437
        return ((char)unchecked((55 + value) + (((value - 10) >> 31) & 0b11111111_11111001)));
    }
    private static byte GetNybble(char value) { // https://stackoverflow.com/a/20695932
        if (ALPHABET.Contains(value)) {
            return ((byte)unchecked(((value - 48) + (((57 - value) >> 31) & 0b1001)) & 0b1111));
        }
        else {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(message: ("invalid hexadecimal character encountered: " + value), paramName: nameof(value));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the criteria for code assessment? Is _performance_ the sole and only one? Many things are not intuitive, like the magic numbers you wanted to avoid (`0xFFFFFFF9`, `0x0000000F`, `48`, `57`, `10`, and so on). Is _readability_ among the criteria? In my personal experience, performance *always* fight each other. Finding a balance is not an easy problem.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko Correctness of implementation is the most important thing IMO, performance second, and readability third. You're absolutely right about the different criteria fighting each other. I felt like hexadecimal format made the functionality of the masks clearer than an alternative like `-7` but now that [numeric literals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#numeric-literal-syntax-improvements) are a thing I think they might make the code read a lot better.

Comment: I will refrain from posting an answer to your question, because I simply can not stick to the hierarchy of the criteria. IMHO, readability goes first, because without it the code is too likely to be broken (violates the correctness criterion -- on which I totally agree). Even if the code is correct today, without readability it will break tomorrow when somebody who maintains it introduces a regression. As for me (I don't deal with bit-wise arithmetic on daily basis) the code is pretty darn hard to read; but this is subjective. I hope other folks will post helpful answers to your good question.

Comment: BTW, I've never known that C# has a concept of a pointer.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko No worries mate; much obliged you gave it a look over at all. I'm normally in your camp as far as readability goes but this particular project is all about exploring the limits of .NET performance for me (without sacrificing correctness of course). I still have a hard time wrapping my head around bitwise/pointer logic but will say that hammering away at it has been extremely rewarding; takes a lot of effort but really helps one understand just what everything costs even if end up not using it in "real world" code.

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Don't reinvent the wheel.

[This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa) tackles the same problem that you've tackled. There are slight differences (e.g. no prefix parameter), but the linked example is immensely more readable and maintainable.

When you're trying to tackle a problem that sounds rather generic, always look for examples online. More often than not, someone else will have already been tackling this problem.

You mentioned that you approached this problem with the intention of **learning** how en/decoding works. Doing things yourself is a great way to learn; and I would indeed suggest that you trying doing something yourself instead of immediately relying on external help.

However, in your pursuit of trying to do it yourself, you dug much too deep. When you started using unmanaged code and pointers, that should've been a red flag that you were overcomplicating your solution.

You didn't really lose anything here, because it was a training exercise. But in a professional setting, your complicated solution must have taken a lot more time, while also lowering readability and making the code less maintainable in the future. And this is where your good intentions ended up doing more harm than good.

### 2. Pointers lower readability

I'm not 100% sure if this unilaterally applies to C#. I think it does, but maybe I'm forgetting some use cases here. However, I am at least certain that your case did not need pointers.

Relative to other "building blocks" of programming, pointers are very difficult to grasp in any sufficiently complex codebase (= most professional codebases). My suggestion is to avoid them whenever possible.
While pointers are of course usable from a technical point of view, they generally detract from the **readability** of the code. Unless you're facing a fringe case (string operations are **not** fringe cases), the unreadability of pointers tends to outweigh the benefits of using them.

An example of an unnecessary pointer is `target` in `GetString()`. There are other ways of solving the problem that do not require a pointer.

```
var result = new string('☠', ((count << 1) + prefix.Length));
fixed (byte* source = &value[0])
fixed (char* target = result) {
    for (var i = 0; i < prefix.Length; i++) {
        *(target + i) = prefix[i];
    }

//...

while (0 < count--) {
    *t = m[*s];

    s++;
    t++;
}
```

Assigning a string character by character is a cumbersome process. It can be performant (since you're working in unmanaged code), but it's ugly and prone to lowering readability.

Compare this to an approach that is more idiomatic (for C#):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append(prefix);

foreach(char c in value)
{
    byte b = Convert.ToByte(c);
    sb.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
}

return sb.ToString();
```

*Note: This is based on the conversion method from the linked answer (cfr the first part of my answer)*

The only two variables I needed were `value` and `prefix`. Everything else could have been omitted.

The majority of your code focuses on **handling pointers** instead of focusing on your main goal (byte to string conversion).

*If a car mechanic spends more time looking for his tools instead of fixing cars, wouldn't you agree that this mechanic is not working efficiently?*

### 3. Bitshifting lowers readability.

```
var result = new string('☠', ((count << 1) + prefix.Length));
```

`(count << 1)` is the same as `count * 2`. However, in the interest of **readability**, you should favor using `count * 2`.

[According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168451/is-shifting-bits-faster-than-multiplying-and-dividing-in-java-net), the compiler will evaluate whether a given multiplication (e.g. `count * 2`) can easily be solved using shift operations.

This means that when you use `count * 2`, that the code has become more readable, and the runtime performance will be the same (since the compiler will still do a bitshift if it's more performant).

*Also note:*
*Bitshifting only works if you wish to multiply by a power of 2, because bits are binary (base 2). This wouldn't work for multiplication by any other number, which makes bitshifting a bad fit for multiplication.*

### 4. You need to invest time into readability.

This chapter is a quick-fire round. I want to highlight a few snippets that are disproportionately unreadable.

**1. Don't rely on magic numbers**

```
private static readonly uint[] m_byteToHexMap = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 256)
    .Select(i => (((uint)(GetChar((byte)(i & 0b1111)) << 16)) | GetChar((byte)(i >> 4))))
    .ToArray();
```

Specifically:

```
(((uint)(GetChar((byte)(i & 0b1111)) << 16)) | GetChar((byte)(i >> 4)))
```

Even after furious Googling, I have no idea how this works. What's `0b1111`? Why `<< 16`? Why `>> 4`? It's pure magic.

Compare this to `Convert.ToByte(c)`. The intention of this tiny snippet is immediately obvious, without relying on a ton of bit-level operations that would require a reader to intensely study the effects of bitshifting and the ASCII value of characters.

> **Note**:
>   Sometimes, magic values are hard to avoid. There are cases where it's pointless to un-magic your code (e.g. the `2` in `Math.Round(myNumber, 2)`).
>
> However, if this is the case, you should still be leaving **comments** in the code that **explain** the purpose/intention of the code.

**2. The intention/purpose of a variable should be understood by its name alone.**

There are times where you stuck to this rule. E.g. the name of your `prefix` variable makes it immediately obvious that this string value will be added to the front of the output. The name aptly describes the purpose of the variable.

But then you also do this:

```
while (0 < count--) {
    *t = m[*s];

    s++;
    t++;
}
```

What is `s`? What is `t`? What is `m`?

Every step of the way, I've had to scroll up to find the declared variable. I've had to look up the same variable several times because I kept forgetting. The fact that these are pointers further compounds the complexity.

```
while (0 < count--) {
    *pTarget = mapping[*pSource];

    pSource++;
    pTarget++;
}
```

Forgoing the argument about not using pointers, the readability has already dramatically improved simply by giving the variables a name that aptly describes the variable and its purpose.

> **Note**:
>   You can of course make exceptions for index variables such as `i`. Index variables are a common occurrence, most developers will immediately assume that this is an integer that will be used to access an array.

### 5. Optional parameters are a C# feature.

You're not using optional parameters for parameters that are actually optional:

```
public static unsafe string GetString(byte[] value, string prefix)        
{
    prefix = (prefix ?? string.Empty);

    //...
```

If you have no prefix, then you would call the method using:

```
GetString(myValue, null);
```

However, if you had used an [optional parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199761/how-can-you-use-optional-parameters-in-c):

```
public static unsafe string GetString(byte[] value, string prefix = "")        
{
```

Then you wouldn't have needed to check add the extra check to see if it is null. If it were null, it will automatically use the supplied value (`""`). This means that **optional parameters will never be null** (unless, of course, you make their default value `null`...)

This also means that you can **omit** optional parameters if you don't need them. If you have no prefix, then you would call the method using:

```
GetString(myValue);
```

Notice how you're not forced to add the `null`.

### 6. Your priorities.

This is a bit off-topic, more a review of your approach to coding and not the code itself.

> Correctness of implementation is the most important thing IMO, performance second, and readability third

1. Correctness of implementation
2. Performance
3. Readability

We can argue about the order of priorities. I think most people would put readability over performance; because readability affects programmer performance, whereas performance affects machine performance.
More often than not, the speed of development is a bigger bottleneck than the processing speed by the server, which makes readability more important than code performance.

However, this is not what I want to talk about now. Instead, I want to pull focus to the fact that **priorities should not be absolute**. Not every performance boost will **always** trump a consideration of readability.

> For the sake of (silly and extreme) example, let's say that you can get a 0.05% performance gain if all your method and variable names exclusively use Chinese characters. You don't speak Chinese, nor do your colleagues.
>
> Would you use Chinese characters in all your methods?

A minuscule performance gain is not worth it when it comes at the cost of making the code twice as hard to read. Even though you put performance before readability, you should still **weigh your options**.

Just because you favor performance over readability, does not mean that you should always sacrifice readability in favor of performance. Instead, look at how much you stand to gain performance wise, and compare it to the cost of lowering readability.
If you can get a massive performance gain for a minor dent in eadability, go for it. If the performance gain is much smaller than the cost of losing readability, don't do it.

I can't really give you a definitive answer here, it's very subjective. But **you need to observe the cost and benefit of a cetain change**, rather than blindly following the priorities you defined in the past.

Comment: I don't think it's really fair to (partially) blame `0b1111` for the lack of readability, that's obviously just a mask used to extract the lower nibble

Comment: @harold: Even a minor comment like `//Bit mask used to extract the lower nibble` would help tremendously. But it's unfair to single out a specific operation and point out that it's readable. The readability is defined by the _aggregate_ complexity of the code base. Every line may make sense in and of itself, but that doesn't mean that the code base itself is readable. Especially in the OP's case, the constant pointer handling dramatically complicates what would have otherwise been a straightforward algorithm.

Comment: I certainly did not say the code as a whole is readable, but you've taken one of the few things that's actually obvious and called it a problem

Comment: @harold: I strongly contest that this is "actually obvious". Not only are the parentheses hard to parse, the operations that are being used are not common (nor simple) enough for an average developer to quickly understand the intention of this oneliner. As I said, it's not so much that one thing is the sole cause of a massive problem, it's that there's a bunch of complex things happening all at once. Splitting that oneliner into several steps would've done wonders, even if you don't un-magic or comment the code (which you should of course still do)

Comment: Yes but I was never talking about the entire line, but a specific part of it that is receiving undue blame. The line has too much stuff on it, nested too deeply, and it's not immediately clear why `uint`s are being made and what they represent. There are lots of problems. But `0b1111` is just a literal representation of a low nibble. If it was written as 15 that would be a problem.

Comment: Downvoted for completely ignoring my criteria. One is fully aware just how unreadable pointers and bitwise arithmetic is to the average person and doesn't even remotely care. Your idiomatic version is what I use to benchmark my code and it's well over 100x slower.

Comment: @Kittoes0124: `One is fully aware just how unreadable pointers and bitwise arithmetic is to the average person and doesn't even remotely care.` If you want to solely focus on computational performance, then that's your prerogative. But your explicit refusal to even consider readable variable names (right off the bat, in your question) is imo unjustifiable, and it  makes me question what it is you expected to get out of a code review. You're painting yourself into a corner, and your approach to coding is not professionally sustainable. You lack readability and **maintainability**.

Comment: @Flater Explicit refusal? I didn't counter your point about variable naming at all, I even called myself out for it in the OP claiming that I believed `m`, `s`, and `t` in particular made the code more readable (because in my mind they are nothing more than an monotone counters, like the traditional`i`). One just isn't about to swap out the usage of bitwise operations and pointers here... my approach this this post might not be professionally sustainable, so what? We're not at work here.

Comment: @Kittoes0124: If you consider your personal opinion as immovably  important, then you preclude a meaningful review. You're considering the variable names based on your current understanding of the algorithm. You're not considering anyone else's point of view.  And to be clear, my point is not about how unreadable it is for those who read this post. If you have to revisit this code in the future, you'll struggle with reading (and maintaining) it too. However, I'm not going to keep arguing my point if you're already convinced your approach is better.

Comment: If you consider my opinion as an immovably important than I'm either communicating incorrectly or your reading comprehension needs work. From the beginning I've acknowledged that my variable names probably need work but left them as is for the OP; clearly I was wrong when I thought that they might add clarity. What I'm not considering is a complete refactor into a style that I could've gone with from the outset; the entire purpose of this exercise for me is to try and make the usage of bitwise operations and pointers as obvious as I can (which I'm also clearly not doing well at).

Comment: @Kittoes0124: I completely agree that well-designed manual memory control (= pointers) will always outperform managed code. However, manual memory control is notoriously **complex** and **hard to debug**. (Furthermore, managed code will always take less time to develop than its pointer-based counterpart.) You're choosing the hard path, _of course_ it's going to be hard to get everything right. This is why we've moved from C# to C++ for most situations, because the **ease of development** more often than not outweighs the benefits of manual memory management.

Comment: Uh... wut? If I wanted to go for ease of development then I would've stuck with the idiomatic solution I started with or used a library that implemented things for me. Instead, I wanted something that was correct in all situations (either a value is translated successfully or a meaningful error is thrown), extremely efficient, and relatively understandable to someone with the prerequisite knowledge and/or persistence. For example:`GetChar` and `GetNybble` are explained thoroughly in the linked SO answers that I derived them from but also make a lot more sense with an ASCII table to reference.

Comment: Let's not forget that you sum your entire post up with `But you need to observe the cost and benefit of a certain change, rather than blindly following the priorities you defined in the past.` and I have: the idiomatic way is generally at least 100x slower in real world benchmarks so how can I justify using it throughout my code base?